# Hardware abstraction in C++ on STM32F4

Tags: c++, embedded

I've recently watched a few talks on implementing easy-to-use hardware abstraction layers in C++ for use on embedded devices such as ARM Cortex-based microcontrollers such as the STM32F4 that I am targeting with this project. I would like some input into whether or not the following usage structure makes sense to the average programmer *and* the embedded programmer due to the amount of hardware that must be normally set up manually when interacting with memory-mapped hardware peripherals in the context of an embedded application. My full project is too big but I will try to boil down the parts I want feedback on as follows:

**startup.cpp**: inital processor boot entry file

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>

/*
 * External definitions from linker for stack, BSS, data, and initialization/constructor
 * functions
 */

extern "C" int __stack_top__;
extern "C" char __bss_start__;
extern "C" char __bss_end__;
extern "C" char __data_start__;
extern "C" char __data_end__;
extern "C" char __data_flash__;
extern "C" void (*__preinit_array_start[])(void);
extern "C" void (*__preinit_array_end[])(void);
extern "C" void (*__init_array_start[])(void);
extern "C" void (*__init_array_end[])(void);

// Prototype definition of main function
int boot_main();

namespace Startup {
/**
 * @brief Default interrupt handler for interrupt vector table
 *
 */
void Default_Handler();
/**
 * @brief Goes through all startup initialization, including:
 *  -- Copies initialization values from flash to RAM
 *  -- Zeros BSS area
 *  -- Calls all initializers and constructors
 *
 */
void Initialize();
}  // namespace Startup

/**
 * @brief Reset handler that exectures the initialization functions then calls main
 *
 */
extern "C" void Reset_Handler() {
    Startup::Initialize();
    boot_main();
    Startup::Default_Handler();
}

void Startup::Initialize() {
    size_t count;

    // Copy static values from flash .data to RAM .data
    count = &__data_end__ - &__data_start__;
    std::memcpy(&__data_start__, &__data_flash__, count);

    // Set BSS area to zero
    count = &__bss_end__ - &__bss_start__;
    std::memset(&__bss_start__, 0, count);

    // Call all initializers & constructors
    size_t i;

    count = __preinit_array_end - __preinit_array_start;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        __preinit_array_start[i]();

    count = __init_array_end - __init_array_start;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        __init_array_start[i]();
}

void Startup::Default_Handler() {
    while (true) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

// NVIC interrupt table
extern "C" void (*const vectors[])(void)
    __attribute__((used, section(".vectors"))) = {(void (*)(void))(&__stack_top__),
                                                  Reset_Handler,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  nullptr,
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler,
                                                  ... { repeat several times } ...
                                                  Startup::Default_Handler};
```

**main.cpp**: main entry file

```
#include "hardware/GPIO.hpp"
#include "hardware/RCC.hpp"

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

int boot_main() {
    RCC &rcc = *new RCC();

    rcc.EnableExternalSystemClock();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
        // Do nothing (busy wait)
    }

    GPIO &gpioc = *new (GPIO::GPIOC) GPIO();
    gpioc.SetMode(GPIO::PIN13, GPIO::Mode::OUTPUT);
    gpioc.SetType(GPIO::PIN13, GPIO::Type::PUSH_PULL);
    gpioc.SetResistor(GPIO::PIN13, GPIO::PUPD::PULL_UP);

    while (true) {
        gpioc.EnableOutput(GPIO::PIN13);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 45000; i++) {
            // Do nothing (busy wait)
        }
        gpioc.DisableOutput(GPIO::PIN13);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 45000; i++) {
            // Do nothing (busy wait)
        }
    }
}
```

**GPIO.cpp**: GPIO class implementation

```
#include "GPIO.hpp"

#include "RCC.hpp"

GPIO::GPIO() {
    // Do nothing
}

void *GPIO::operator new(std::size_t) {
    // Enable GPIOA clock
    RCC &rcc = *new RCC();
    rcc.EnableGPIO(GPIO::GPIOA);

    // Return GPIOA address
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(0x40020000);
}

void *GPIO::operator new(std::size_t, const enum gpio_selection n) {
    RCC &rcc = *new RCC();
    rcc.EnableGPIO(n);

    // Return GPIO address
    auto address = 0x40020000 + n * 0x400;
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(address);
}

void GPIO::SetMode(enum gpio_pin pin_num, GPIO::Mode mode) {
    uint32_t set_moder = this->MODER.reg;
    set_moder &= ~(0b11 << (2 * pin_num));
    switch (mode) {
        case GPIO::Mode::OUTPUT:
            set_moder |= (0b01 << (2 * pin_num));
            break;
        case GPIO::Mode::ALTERNATE:
            set_moder |= (0b10 << (2 * pin_num));
            break;
        case GPIO::Mode::ANALOG:
            set_moder |= (0b11 << (2 * pin_num));
            break;
        default:
            // Do nothing
            break;
    }
    this->MODER.reg = set_moder;
}
... { several other method implementations } ...
```

**GPIO.hpp**: GPIO class header

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

#pragma once

using reg32_t = volatile uint32_t;
using reg16_t = volatile uint16_t;

class GPIO {
  private:
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t MODER15 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER14 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER13 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER12 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER11 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER10 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER9 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER8 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER7 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER6 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER5 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER4 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER3 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER2 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER1 : 2;
            reg32_t MODER0 : 2;
        } bits;
    } MODER;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 16;
            reg32_t OT15 : 1;
            reg32_t OT14 : 1;
            reg32_t OT13 : 1;
            reg32_t OT12 : 1;
            reg32_t OT11 : 1;
            reg32_t OT10 : 1;
            reg32_t OT9 : 1;
            reg32_t OT8 : 1;
            reg32_t OT7 : 1;
            reg32_t OT6 : 1;
            reg32_t OT5 : 1;
            reg32_t OT4 : 1;
            reg32_t OT3 : 1;
            reg32_t OT2 : 1;
            reg32_t OT1 : 1;
            reg32_t OT0 : 1;
        } bits;
    } OTYPER;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t OSPEEDR15 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR14 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR13 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR12 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR11 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR10 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR9 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR8 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR7 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR6 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR5 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR4 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR3 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR2 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR1 : 2;
            reg32_t OSPEEDR0 : 2;
        } bits;
    } OSPEEDR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t PUPDR15 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR14 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR13 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR12 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR11 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR10 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR9 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR8 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR7 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR6 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR5 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR4 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR3 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR2 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR1 : 2;
            reg32_t PUPDR0 : 2;
        } bits;
    } PUPDR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 16;
            reg32_t IDR15 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR14 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR13 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR12 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR11 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR10 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR9 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR8 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR7 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR6 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR5 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR4 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR3 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR2 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR1 : 1;
            reg32_t IDR0 : 1;
        } bits;
    } IDR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 16;
            reg32_t ODR15 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR14 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR13 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR12 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR11 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR10 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR9 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR8 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR7 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR6 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR5 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR4 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR3 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR2 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR1 : 1;
            reg32_t ODR0 : 1;
        } bits;
    } ODR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t BR15 : 1;
            reg32_t BR14 : 1;
            reg32_t BR13 : 1;
            reg32_t BR12 : 1;
            reg32_t BR11 : 1;
            reg32_t BR10 : 1;
            reg32_t BR9 : 1;
            reg32_t BR8 : 1;
            reg32_t BR7 : 1;
            reg32_t BR6 : 1;
            reg32_t BR5 : 1;
            reg32_t BR4 : 1;
            reg32_t BR3 : 1;
            reg32_t BR2 : 1;
            reg32_t BR1 : 1;
            reg32_t BR0 : 1;
            reg32_t BS15 : 1;
            reg32_t BS14 : 1;
            reg32_t BS13 : 1;
            reg32_t BS12 : 1;
            reg32_t BS11 : 1;
            reg32_t BS10 : 1;
            reg32_t BS9 : 1;
            reg32_t BS8 : 1;
            reg32_t BS7 : 1;
            reg32_t BS6 : 1;
            reg32_t BS5 : 1;
            reg32_t BS4 : 1;
            reg32_t BS3 : 1;
            reg32_t BS2 : 1;
            reg32_t BS1 : 1;
            reg32_t BS0 : 1;
        } bits;
        struct {
            reg16_t BR;
            reg16_t BS;
        } split;
    } BSRR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 15;
            reg32_t LCKK : 1;
            reg32_t LCK15 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK14 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK13 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK12 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK11 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK10 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK9 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK8 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK7 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK6 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK5 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK4 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK3 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK2 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK1 : 1;
            reg32_t LCK0 : 1;
        } bits;
    } LCKR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t AFRL7 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL6 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL5 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL4 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL3 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL2 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL1 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRL0 : 4;
        } bits;
    } AFRL;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t AFRH15 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH14 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH13 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH12 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH11 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH10 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH9 : 4;
            reg32_t AFRH8 : 4;
        } bits;
    } AFRH;

  public:
    enum gpio_selection { GPIOA = 0, GPIOB = 1, GPIOC = 2, GPIOD = 3, GPIOE = 4, GPIOH = 7 };
    enum gpio_pin {
        PIN0,
        PIN1,
        PIN2,
        PIN3,
        PIN4,
        PIN5,
        PIN6,
        PIN7,
        PIN8,
        PIN9,
        PIN10,
        PIN11,
        PIN12,
        PIN13,
        PIN14,
        PIN15
    };
    enum class Mode { INPUT, OUTPUT, ALTERNATE, ANALOG };
    enum class Type { PUSH_PULL, OPEN_DRAIN };
    enum class PUPD { NONE, PULL_UP, PULL_DOWN };

    GPIO();

    void *operator new(std::size_t);
    void *operator new(std::size_t, const enum gpio_selection n);

    void SetMode(enum gpio_pin pin_num, GPIO::Mode mode);
    GPIO::Mode GetMode(enum gpio_pin pin_num);
    void SetType(enum gpio_pin pin_num, GPIO::Type type);
    void SetResistor(enum gpio_pin pin_num, enum GPIO::PUPD pupd_type);
    void EnableOutput(enum gpio_pin pin_num);
    void DisableOutput(enum gpio_pin pin_num);
    bool GetOutput(enum gpio_pin pin_num);

    enum gpio_selection GetGPIO() {
        return static_cast<enum gpio_selection>((reinterpret_cast<int>(this) & 0xFFFF) / 0x400);
    }
};

static_assert(sizeof(GPIO) == 10 * sizeof(reg32_t), "GPIO contains padding bytes.");
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<GPIO>::value, "GPIO isn't standard layout.");
```

**RCC.cpp**: RCC class implementation

```
#include "RCC.hpp"

#include "FLASH.hpp"
#include "GPIO.hpp"
#include "PWR.hpp"

RCC::RCC() {
    // Do nothing
}

void *RCC::operator new(std::size_t) {
    return reinterpret_cast<void *>(0x40023800);
}

void RCC::EnableExternalSystemClock() {
    // Enable HSE
    this->CR.bits.HSEON = 1;
    while (this->CR.bits.HSERDY == 0) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Enable power controller
    this->APB1ENR.bits.PWREN = 1;

    // Configure voltage regulator scaling
    PWR &power = *new PWR();
    power.SetRegulatorScale(PWR::Scale::DIV2);

    // Enable flash prefetch & caches
    FLASH &flash = *new FLASH();
    flash.EnablePrefetchCache();

    // Set PLL scalers
    constexpr auto pll_clocks = RCC::CalculatePLLClocks(HSE_CRYSTAL_FREQ_HZ, TARGET_SYSTEM_CLOCK);
    this->PLLCFGR.bits.PLLM = std::get<0>(pll_clocks);
    this->PLLCFGR.bits.PLLN = std::get<1>(pll_clocks);
    this->PLLCFGR.bits.PLLP = std::get<2>(pll_clocks);

    // Calculate actual system clock
    constexpr auto sys_clock =
        RCC::CalculateSysClock(HSE_CRYSTAL_FREQ_HZ, std::get<0>(pll_clocks),
                               std::get<1>(pll_clocks), std::get<2>(pll_clocks));

    // Set APB scalers
    constexpr auto lsapb2_prescaler = RCC::CalculateLSAPB2Prescaler(sys_clock);
    this->CFGR.bits.HPRE = 0b000;
    this->CFGR.bits.PPRE1 = lsapb2_prescaler;
    this->CFGR.bits.PPRE2 = 0b000;

    // Set PLL source
    this->PLLCFGR.bits.PLLSRC = 1;

    // Enable PLL
    this->CR.bits.PLLON = 1;
    while (this->CR.bits.PLLRDY == 0) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    // Set clock source
    this->CFGR.bits.SW = 0b01;
    while (this->CFGR.bits.SWS != 0b01) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

**RCC.hpp**: RCC class header

```
#include "GPIO.hpp"

#include <cmath>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#pragma once

#define HSE_CRYSTAL_FREQ_HZ 25000000
#define HSI_CRYSTAL_FREQ_HZ 16000000

#define TARGET_SYSTEM_CLOCK 84000000

using reg32_t = volatile uint32_t;

class RCC {
  private:
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 4;
            reg32_t PLLI2SRDY : 1;
            reg32_t PLLI2SON : 1;
            reg32_t PLLRDY : 1;
            reg32_t PLLON : 1;
            reg32_t : 4;
            reg32_t CSSON : 1;
            reg32_t HSEBYP : 1;
            reg32_t HSERDY : 1;
            reg32_t HSEON : 1;
            reg32_t HSICAL : 8;
            reg32_t HSITRIM : 5;
            reg32_t : 1;
            reg32_t HSIRDY : 1;
            reg32_t HSION : 1;
        } bits;
    } CR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 4;
            reg32_t PLLQ : 4;
            reg32_t : 1;
            reg32_t PLLSRC : 1;
            reg32_t : 4;
            reg32_t PLLP : 2;
            reg32_t : 1;
            reg32_t PLLN : 9;
            reg32_t PLLM : 6;
        } bits;
    } PLLCFGR;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t MCO2 : 2;
            reg32_t MCO2PRE : 3;
            reg32_t MCO1PRE : 3;
            reg32_t I2SSRC : 1;
            reg32_t MCO1 : 2;
            reg32_t RTCPRE : 5;
            reg32_t PPRE2 : 3;
            reg32_t PPRE1 : 3;
            reg32_t : 2;
            reg32_t HPRE : 4;
            reg32_t SWS : 2;
            reg32_t SW : 2;
        } bits;
    } CFGR;
    reg32_t CIR;
    reg32_t AHB1RSTR;
    reg32_t AHB2RSTR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t APB1RSTR;
    reg32_t APB2RSTR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 9;
            reg32_t DMA2EN : 1;
            reg32_t DMA1EN : 1;
            reg32_t : 8;
            reg32_t CRCEN : 1;
            reg32_t : 4;
            reg32_t GPIOHEN : 1;
            reg32_t : 2;
            reg32_t GPIOEEN : 1;
            reg32_t GPIODEN : 1;
            reg32_t GPIOCEN : 1;
            reg32_t GPIOBEN : 1;
            reg32_t GPIOAEN : 1;
        } bits;
    } AHB1ENR;
    reg32_t AHB2ENR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    union {
        reg32_t reg;
        struct {
            reg32_t : 3;
            reg32_t PWREN : 1;
            reg32_t : 4;
            reg32_t I2C3EN : 1;
            reg32_t I2C2EN : 1;
            reg32_t I2C1EN : 1;
            reg32_t : 3;
            reg32_t USART2EN : 1;
            reg32_t : 1;
            reg32_t SPI3EN : 1;
            reg32_t SPI2EN : 1;
            reg32_t : 2;
            reg32_t WWDGEN : 1;
            reg32_t : 7;
            reg32_t TIM5EN : 1;
            reg32_t TIM4EN : 1;
            reg32_t TIM3EN : 1;
            reg32_t TIM2EN : 1;
        } bits;
    } APB1ENR;
    reg32_t APB2ENR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t AHB1LPENR;
    reg32_t AHB2LPENR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t APB1LPENR;
    reg32_t APB2LPENR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t BDCR;
    reg32_t CSR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t SSCGR;
    reg32_t PLLI2SCFGR;
    reg32_t : 32;
    reg32_t DCKCFGR;

  public:
    RCC();

    void *operator new(std::size_t);

    void EnableExternalSystemClock();
    
    inline void EnableGPIO(const enum GPIO::gpio_selection selection) {
        this->AHB1ENR.reg |= (1 << selection);
        // switch (selection) {
        //  case GPIO::GPIOA:
        //      this->AHB1ENR.bits.GPIOAEN = 1;
        //      break;
        //  case GPIO::GPIOB:
        //      this->AHB1ENR.bits.GPIOBEN = 1;
        //      break;
        //  case GPIO::GPIOC:
        //      this->AHB1ENR.bits.GPIOCEN = 1;
        //      break;
        //  case GPIO::GPIOD:
        //      this->AHB1ENR.bits.GPIODEN = 1;
        //      break;
        //  case GPIO::GPIOE:
        //      this->AHB1ENR.bits.GPIOEEN = 1;
        //      break;
        //  case GPIO::GPIOH:
        //      this->AHB1ENR.bits.GPIOHEN = 1;
        //      break;
        //  default:
        //      break;  // Do nothing
        // }
    }

    inline void DisableGPIO(const enum GPIO::gpio_selection selection) {
        this->AHB1ENR.reg &= ~(1 << selection);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Calculate system clock frequency through PLL register values
     *
     * @param hs_crystal_freq HS clock signal frequency in Hz
     * @param pll_m M divisor
     * @param pll_n N mulitplier
     * @param pll_p P divisor in register form
     * @return constexpr int System clock frequency
     */
    static constexpr int CalculateSysClock(uint32_t hs_crystal_freq, uint32_t pll_m, uint32_t pll_n,
                                           uint32_t pll_p) {
        return ((hs_crystal_freq / pll_m) * pll_n) / ((pll_p * 2) + 2);
    }

    /**
     * @brief Returns best match for PLL M, N, and P register values for main MCU PLL
     *
     * @param hs_crystal_freq Input HS clock signal frequency in Hz
     * @param target Target system clock frequency
     * @return constexpr std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t> M, N, and P values in tuple
     */
    static constexpr std::tuple<uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t>
    CalculatePLLClocks(uint32_t hs_crystal_freq, uint32_t target) {
        uint32_t pll_m = 1, optimum_pll_n = 0, optimum_pll_p = 0;
        int64_t min_diff = INT64_MAX;

        // Calculate PLL M value to satisfy frequency constraints
        while (hs_crystal_freq / pll_m > 2100000) {
            pll_m++;
        }

        // Iterate through all values of N and P to find closest match to target
        for (uint32_t pll_n = 430; pll_n > 50; pll_n--) {
            for (uint32_t pll_p = 2; pll_p <= 8; pll_p += 2) {
                // Calculate system clock with crystal, M, N, and P
                uint32_t clock =
                    RCC::CalculateSysClock(hs_crystal_freq, pll_m, pll_n, (pll_p - 2) / 2);
                if ((hs_crystal_freq / pll_m) * pll_n < 432000000 && clock < 84000000) {
                    // Calcualte absolute difference between target and calculated clock
                    int64_t diff = (static_cast<int64_t>(target) - static_cast<int64_t>(clock));
                    diff *= ((diff < 0) ? -1 : 1);

                    // If it's closer than previously saved result, overwrite it
                    if (diff <= min_diff) {
                        min_diff = diff;
                        optimum_pll_n = pll_n;
                        optimum_pll_p = pll_p;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Return closest answer in register form
        return {pll_m, optimum_pll_n, (optimum_pll_p - 2) / 2};
    }

    /**
     * @brief Calculate system clock frequency through target clock frequency
     *
     * @param hs_crystal_freq HS clock signal frequency in Hz
     * @return constexpr int System clock frequency
     */
    static constexpr int GetSystemClock(uint32_t hs_crystal_freq) {
        auto pll_clocks = RCC::CalculatePLLClocks(hs_crystal_freq, TARGET_SYSTEM_CLOCK);

        return RCC::CalculateSysClock(hs_crystal_freq, std::get<0>(pll_clocks),
                                      std::get<1>(pll_clocks), std::get<2>(pll_clocks));
    }

    /**
     * @brief Calcualte APB2 clock prescaler
     *
     * @param sys_clock Current system clock
     * @return constexpr int APB2 prescaler value
     */
    static constexpr int CalculateLSAPB2Prescaler(uint32_t sys_clock) {
        int divisor = 1;

        while (sys_clock / divisor > 42000000) {
            divisor *= 2;
        }

        switch (divisor) {
            case 1:
                return 0b000;
            case 2:
                return 0b100;
            case 4:
                return 0b101;
            case 8:
                return 0b110;
            case 16:
                return 0b111;
        }
    }
};

static_assert(sizeof(RCC) == 36 * sizeof(reg32_t), "RCC contains padding bytes.");
static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<RCC>::value, "RCC isn't standard layout.");
```

What I like about my current implementation is that as long as I turn on `-flto` and `-O2` then it pretty much inlines everything into ResetHandler which is very nice. I also use `constexpr` for automatic calculation of system registers at compile-time. My primary question with this implementation is: does it make sense to automatically enable the RCC registers for the appropriate GPIO peripheral when "allocating"/creating an instance of the class? Or should I leave it to the application programmer to deal with such a hardware task themselves? The class will be useless without the RCC registers enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the `reg32_t` type alias and the good use of binary literals. The `static_assert()`s are also a great way to prevent accidental mistakes, especially with bit fields where it's hard to spot if you added one bit too many.

## Use of placement `new`

The point of `new` is to create a *new* object. Placement `new` creates a new object at a given location. However, the hardware registers are already there, you don't have to create them. So I would rather not use placement `new`, but just write a `static` member function that returns a pointer to the right memory location:

```
class RCC {
    ...
public:
    RCC() = delete;
    ...
    static RCC *get() {
        return reinterpret_cast<RCC *>(0x40023800);
        // return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<RCC *>(0x40023800)); // C++17
    }
};
```

Since C++17, you should use [`std::launder()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) to tell the compiler and static analysis tools that there really is a live object at that address, so it won't treat any access to it as undefined behavior.

While overloading operator `new()` and [calling it multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524249/is-it-well-defined-legal-to-placement-new-multiple-times-at-the-same-address) is fine in some cases, consider what would happen if you added constructors and destructors to your classes (for example, to ensure that the registers are in a well-defined state at startup, or to ensure all pins will be high-impedance when you stop using a hardware peripheral).

Another reason against your use of placement `new` is that code like `FOO &f = *new FOO()` looks like an instant memory leak, and might even cause some static analyzers to complain about it.

Since you are using `__attribute__((section))` anyway, consider using sections to declare global instances of your classes at the right address, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067811/how-to-place-a-variable-at-a-given-absolute-address-in-memory-with-gcc).

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

In C++ you almost never have to use `this->`. I would remove it wherever it is unneeded.

## Don't busy wait

Busy waiting uses CPU cycles unnecessarily, using more power which drains batteries faster and generates heat. On a STM32F4, you might want to go to sleep mode in the loop in `main()`, which halts the CPU until an interrupt arrives. To toggle pin 13, you can set up a timer interrupt.

In some cases it is fine to busy wait if you know it's just for a few cycles, like when waiting for `PLLRDY` to become set.

## Inconsistent enums

Some `enum` types are all lower-case, some start with a capital. I would use a consistent way to format type names, regardless of whether it is a `struct`, `union`, `enum` or `enum class`, and make sure it is different from how you format variables. Also, sometimes you add `enum` in front of an existing enum name, but that is not necessary in C++. For example, you can write:

```
void SetMode(gpio_pin pin_num, GPIO::Mode mode);
```

## Casting pointers to integers

While casting a pointer to an `int` might work for your use case, it is more correct to cast then to `std::uintptr_t`. This type is guaranteed to be large enough to fit a whole pointer.

## Prefer using `static constexpr` for constants

In C++ it is hardly ever necessary to use macros anymore. To declare a constant, prefer `static constexpr`, like so:

```
static constexpr std::uint32_t HSE_CRYSTAL_FREQ_HZ = 25000000;
```

## Avoid `std::tuple` in non-generic code

`std::tuple` can be very useful when writing generic code, especially in variadic templates. But they are otherwise a bit cumbersome to work with, in particular you need to use `get<>()` to access tuple elements, and then you have to remember the order in which elements are stored. Instead, you can just create a `struct`:

```
struct PLLClocks {
    uint32_t pll_m;
    uint32_t pll_n;
    uint32_t pll_p;
};
```

And then let `CalculatePLLClocks()` return a `PLLClocks`.

## Default switch cases

In `SetMode()`, I would change `default` to `case GPIO::Mode::INPUT`. This makes it clear that you handle the case of input pins, and by not having a `default` case, the compiler will be able to warn if you ever have an enum value that you didn't handle inside the `switch`-statement.

Comment: Great advice, thank you. The busy waits are there for testing reasons. Once I get the systick timer working correctly and I have an atomic static global counter then I will replace the loop with a proper time-based delay. I may go further and introduce a context/task switcher as well. To your first point, my usage of `new` is based off the talks that I have watched and the main reason they state for using it is that the constructor will be called after the call to `new` is complete. How will a static method accomplish this task?

Comment: Your current constructors are not doing anything, so they don't need to be called. If you use `new` to get a pointer to a peripheral, and more than one part of the code needs to access the same peripheral, then your `new` method would risk having the constructor called multiple times. In any case, the `get()` method in my example could be modified to only call some function the first time `get()` is called, and that could serve as the constructor. Using linker sections might be the cleanest way to solve this though.